# ForEach Lamda expression c#

Tags: c#, linq

How do you make this into 1 line of code:

```
foreach (var item in List.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true))
                    {
                        item.box= "done";
                        
                    }
```

something like this, but that syntax is wrong.

```
List.ForEach(x=>x.box = done, List.Where(x=>x.IsSelected ==true));
```

Comment: This is a *very* often posted question. Long story short: *never* modify objects with linq, as Linq is for **querying**, not **updating** objects.

Comment: I see, Thank you.